# Knockout Foreach loop rendering too many elements

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm using a knockout foreach loop to render a set of divs, the loop works however it is rendering each of the array items three times(which is the length of the array) before rendering the next row.

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: { data: activitySubList } ">
     <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }">
         <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

the resulting markup looks like this:

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: activitySubList, includeDestroyed: false }">
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow0">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                
   </div>                            
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow0">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                 
   </div>                             
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow0">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                 
   </div>                            
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix odd" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow1">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                
   </div>                             
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix odd" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow1">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                 
   </div>                             
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix odd" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow1">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                 
   </div>                             
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow2">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                 
   </div>                          
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow2">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                 
   </div>                             
   <div class="tblRow ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="css: { odd: $index() % 2 }, attr: { id: 'actRow' + $index() }" id="actRow2">
      <div class="rowCell editCell"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>                                 
   </div>
</div>
```

In short the loop is rendering each element the array.length() (in this case 3 times) before moving to render the next element.

EDIT: activitySubList is an ko.observableArray with 3 elements.

EDIT 2:  I realize that this question was not really asked correctly, but the issue was resolved.  It ended up not having anything to do with the for each loop, but that the form it's self was being bound multiple times creating the repeated data

Comment: I think you really need to be able to replicate this in a [mcve] to get a good answer or explanation.

Comment: Show what `activitySubList ` is... how it's constructed, how it's populated, what it is, etc.

Comment: as the activitySubList is full of business specific information, I can't really show it, but as stated in my edit it is a knockout observable array that is populated with three elements, I can tell that is working by viewing it in the visual studio watch, the loop however renders nine rows when it should only render three

Comment: You don't need to display all of your secrets here, but if you can't / won't show how you're creating or binding your data, there is no help for you. You can create objects with made up names and fake data that shows HOW you are trying to do it, otherwise people on here aren't mind readers.

Comment: It would be great if you provide `fiddle` for this issue.

Comment: You've included the original template, but perhaps that's not really what Knockout is getting. Use the browser's development tools to check the actual HTML that's coming from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a sketched out implementation of your data binding, as others have commented. Assuming that 'activitySubList' is your var, have you tried this?

```
<div data-bind="foreach: activitySubList">
```

Comment: Or this:
 <!-- ko foreach: activitySubList -->
       
    <!-- /ko -->

Probably should take a look at knockout docs
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html